# C fopen filename parameter as a dynamic variable

Tags: c, ftp

I want to have the function fopen's filename parameter as a dynamic variable that takes in a ftp client input for my ftp server. I have tried numerous different ways both on this forum and on google but "filename" will still not be recognized by fopen.

```
else if (strncmp(client->input, "retr", 4) == 0) {

            char fname[1024];  
            // COMMAND LINE: retr filePATHNAME thats why +5       
            strcpy(fname, client->input+5); 

        if(fopen(fname, "r") != NULL) {
        ...
```

If I put **fopen("/pub/test.txt" , "r")**, it works so it has to do with something with spaces or quotations or type.

But if i try to do it on the client command line with **retr /pub/test.txt** or even **retr "/pub/test.txt"** fopen does not work and will not open the file.

Been stuck on this for the longest time, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I suggest you log the file name your server tries to open.  It's probably not what you think.  Be sure to use a log format that reveals trailing whitespace / newlines, as the presence of such additional characters is one of the more likely problems.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Im new to C and all this stuff so Im not quite sure how to log it. I've tried printing what fname gives, and it is just printing exactly what  I am inputting.

Comment: Also if you are on a platform that has [valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org) you should check for memory problems like unintialized bytes or invalid reads or writes.

Comment: @pkmangg, at its simplest, logging the filename could just mean printing it, in a suitable format, to stdout.

Comment: It's also possible that `client->input+5` is not properly NUL terminated.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've done printf("%s", fname); and it is printing what I want.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks you helped me solve it.

Comment: Note that it is often beneficial to use a format like `printf("File: [%s]\n", client->input+5);` to show more exactly what the file name looks like.  This shows more clearly embedded newlines, carriage returns; it doesn't show trailing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

Thanks to @user3386109 for the hint.

I basically had to clear all the spaces, new lines for the input

```
strtok(client->input+5,"\r\n\t");
```